# Availability Group Read Only Routing Not Working for SQL Logins

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2017, read-only-routing, sql-authentication

We have following config of Availability Group:

```
server1.domain.com - primary
server2.domain.com - sync secondary
server3.domain.com - async secondary

sql-listener.domain.com - availability group listener DNS name
```

Recently we have setup Read Only Routing (ROR)
Read Only Routing URLs:

```
server1 - TCP://server1.domain.com:1433
server2 - TCP://server2.domain.com:1433
server3 - TCP://server3.domain.com:1433
```

Read Only Routing Lists:

```
server1: server2, server3, server1
server2: server1, server3, server2
server3: server2, server1, server3
```

It worked fine when tested in SSMS using Windows Authentication Login (Domain\MyLogin) with Options >> Additional Connection Parameters tab -> ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly

While `server1` is primary, I connect in SSMS to AG Listener (sql-listener.domain.com) using above parameter and run `select @@servername`, and it shows `server 2`, which means ROR works

Issues/Questions:

When I try to connect in SSMS to AG Listener using SQL Authentication Login (SQLAuthLogin), and `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` parameter, and then run `select @@servername`, it shows me `server1`

`>>> So in my case, ROR does not work with SQL Authentication Login
is there any way to fix this ?`

add: double checked SQLAuthLogin's SID on server1 and server2 - SID is the same, SQLAuthLogin can login to both servers and query MyDatabase just fine

Comment: Have you checked the errorlog in Server2/Server3 for failed logins from said SQL logins?

Comment: This might similar case: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245389/185080. question defined nicely. up voted!

Comment: @SeanGallardy checked the errorlog but there is no records related to failed logins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was not in SQL or Windows Authentication methods, but in default_database setting

Found that for my Windows Authentication Login, `default_database = [MyDatabase]` (which participates in availability group), while my SQL Authentication Login has `default_database = [master]`

Because of above setting, while connecting in SSMS using Windows Authentication, Read Only Routing worked right after `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` was specified. For the SQL Authentication Login, not only `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` needs to be specified, but also it should contain `Initial Catalog=[MyDatabase]`

Adding `Initial Catalog=[MyDatabase]` fixed the issue, SQL Authentication Login could  connect and was directed to Read-Only secondary

[image]